# Change the name (namespace) of website project

Tags: visual-studio, project-management, namespaces

I am creating a new ASP.NET MVC Web Application in C# using Visual Studio 2010. We haven't decided on the name of our project so are using an arbitrary name for the moment to allow us to get stuck into development. Meanwhile, a brand and new name is being developed so in a month or so this arbitrary name will be redundant.

The question is, once the new project name comes into play do we continue development using the old name or is there an easy way to switch to the new name, changing the namespace and project name etc? I guess this can be done by a finding and replacing etc but wondered if there was a more formal way of doing this?

Out of interest, does anyone know how this works in companies with large development teams? For instance with Microsoft we hear of projects in development months before the release date and they often change name just before release. Presumably they don't work with this name during the entire development period.

Not a completely typical programming question, sorry if its in the wrong place.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: I guess that this is why Microsoft projects have "codenames". Namespace name may be changed using some smart refactoring tool like Resharper.

Comment: Is this a Web Application Project (File->New Project), or a Web Site "Project" (File->New Web Site)?

Comment: It's a Web Application Project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any nice way beside ctrl+H

Yet sometimes adding two projects under the same solution is acceptable.
Just adding using/import at the relevant places - and it should work.

I know that the two projects should be quiet distinct to make this solution good - but it worth a second of thinking of.

If you find a decent way - please share... we all suffered from missing spots in the ctrl+h method :)

Answer (score 0):

in my thinking it is possible to rename the project for doing that you can use the property to change the name of project you want.

open the project going to project property  change the name their. the namespace change after next compile. maybe you need to delete the dll component from the bin..

the next thing is that visual studio never forget old name of your project for changing them rename the sln or sui project setting file then next time you can see the name [new] in title bar.

i hope this is not a big task for rename.

Answer (score 0):

Another important thing to remember is to remove the old dll from your web site if you are not wiping out the existing site when you publish. If you don't do this, you may get a cryptic 500.0 error. It turns out that unless your routing specifies namespaces, you can end up with conflicting routes because of the old dll left in the bin folder.